# как сделать автоматическое обращение к функции в определенное время?

Tags: python, python-3.x, планирование

Функция обращается к ссылке и скачивает видео и сохраняет его, мне надо чтоб она это делала автоматически в определенное время суток заданное мной, как это сделать?

```
link = 'http://блабла/test.mp4'

def save_videos(link):
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects = True)
    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Либо через `crontab` в системе (или другой шедулер), либо через питон библиотеку `scheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `schedule`

Тут пример вызова функции `save_videos` с передачей значения их переменной `link` каждый день в 7 утра:

```
import time

# pip install schedule
import schedule

...

schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(save_videos, link=link)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```